# How to re-use the same SELECT query with two different resultMaps in MyBatis?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have a mapper `resultMap` that has two collections that I need to select inline

```xml
<collection property="companies" ofType="Company" column="user_id" select="selectCompanies"/>
<collection property="companyGroups" ofType="CompanyGroup" column="user_id" select="selectCompanyGroups"/>
```

The query is exactly the same for the two collections but the resulting maps are very different from each other. Is there a way that I can use the same select with two different `resultMaps`?

I have to run these queries inline because if it were part of the main query, it would result in an extra couple thousand records due to left joins.

I can't use SQL because that only allows for static parameter resolution, instead of dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can use the same select with two different `resultMap`s?

Yes, you can use the same select with two different `resultMap`s like this.

```xml
<mapper namespace="com.example.PersonRepository">
    <!-- The common re-usable SELECT query -->
    <sql id="select-part">
        SELECT first_name, last_name, ...other attributes... 
        FROM table
        <!-- You may use dynamic parameters here the same way as in a regular query -->
        <where>
            <if test="searchParams.firstName != null">
                first_name = #{searchParams.firstName}
            </if>
            <if test="searchParams.lastName != null">
                and last_name = #{searchParams.lastName}
            </if>
        </where>
    </sql>

    <!-- Method List<Type1> getAsType1(SearchParams searchParams) -->
    <select id="getAsType1" resultMap="map1">
        <include refid="select-part"/>
    </select>

    <!-- Method List<Type2> getAsType2(SearchParams searchParams) -->
    <select id="getAsType2" resultMap="map2">
        <include refid="select-part"/>
    </select>

    <resultMap id="map1" type="Type1">
        ...
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="map2" type="Type2">
        ...
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

Don't worry about `where` and `and` clauses, MyBatis will [handle them correctly](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#trimWhereSet).

Your Java code may look like this:

```java
package com.example;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
// Other imports

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository {
    public List<Type1> getAsType1(@Param("searchParams") SearchParams searchParams);
    public List<Type2> getAsType2(@Param("searchParams") SearchParams searchParams);
}
```

and `SearchParams` is just a POJO with `firstName`, `lastName` etc.

Comment: Ah perfect. So it works just like a regular query parameter map. Thank you very much for your guidance